# Analyzing a hand-drawn flowchart diagram

Tags: opencv, object-detection

I'm trying to detect objects and text in a hand-drawn diagram.

My goal is to be able to "parse" something like [this](https://hlksow.dm1.livefilestore.com/y2pWx-IR9GGEpEPKUClCy0Ukpr7ymPXxcMsMFbPkjwOxgFqjJ6JFmMiwsLNZlLxu9VAYpy637mD1vg5NUyj-sKuIuztjETwIYUItw9I6aBj__k/WP_20130729_001.jpg?psid=1) into an object structure for further processing.
My first aim is to detect text, lines and boxes (arrows etc... are not important (for now ;))

I can do Dilatation, Erosion, Otsu thresholding, Invert etc and easily get to something like [this](https://uxnrbg.dm1.livefilestore.com/y2pdcalV6UGa4YgryMXEkpL5-znYPT90tul7gI_mwalCynmsjHP7CskLPR2nDFkELNKh4_6hSUo_WB39FM0lqXGvr9ixu_XwgAdcTv4CscUjF4/BinaryDiagram.png?psid=1)

What I need some guidance for are the next steps.
I've have several ideas:

1. Contour Analysis
2. OCR using UNIPEN
3. Edge detection

**Contour Analysis**

I've been reading about "Contour Analysis for Image Recognition in C#" on CodeProject which could be a great way to recognize boxes etc. but my issue is that the boxes are connected and therefore do not form separate objects to match with a template. 
Therefore I need some advises IF this is a feasible way to go.

**OCR using UNIPEN**

I would like to use UNIPEN (see "Large pattern recognition system using multi neural networks" on CodeProject) to recognize handwritten letters and then "remove" them from the image leaving only the boxes and lines.

**Edge detection**
Another way could be to detect all lines and corners and in that way infer the boxes and lines that the image consist of. In that case ideas on how to straighten the lines and find the 90 degree corners would be helpful.

Generally, I think I just need some pointers on which strategy to apply, not code samples (though it would be great ;))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to answer about the contour analysis and the lines between them.

If you need to turn the interconnected boxes into separate objects, that can be achieved easily enough:

1. close the gaps in the box edges with morphological closing
2. perform connected components labeling and look for compact objects (e.g. objects whose area is close to the area of their bounding box)

You will get the insides of the boxes. These can be elliptical or rectangular or any shape you may find in common diagrams, the contour analysis can tell you which. A problem may arise for enclosed background areas (e.g. the space between the ABC links in your example diagram). You might eliminate these on the criterion that their bounding box overlaps with multiple other objects' bounding boxes.

Now find line segments with HoughLinesP. If a segment finishes or starts within a certain distance of the edge of one of the objects, you can assume it is connected to that object.

As an added touch you could try to detect arrow ends on either side by checking the width profile of the line segments in a neighbourhood of their endpoints.

It is an interesting problem, I will try to remember it and give it to my students to grit their teeth on.

Comment: Thank you for pushing me in the right direction. Connected Component Labeling (CCL) is really powerful!

This is what I ended up with: First I used CCL to get the components and filtered out the blobs that was inside other blobs. That gave me the boxes. Then I used polygon offset to find the outer area of each box and removed these from the image. That left me with the lines only. Using HoughLines turned out to be difficult as some lines were angled. Instead I just did another CCL on the line segments and measured which boxes they touched. Simple and clean. Once Again Thank you for your help

Comment: And ohh. As a sideeffect I now have nice images of the inside of each box, so now it's just a matter of finding a good hand writing OCR approach :)

Comment: Hi, I m working on similar kind of thing, basically converting flowchart drawn on paper to digital flowchart by optically scanning it. How did you solve the OCR problem, extracting text from specific box correctly?

Comment: I think handwriting OCR is as of yet an unsolved problem. OCR tends to work satisfactorily if you know the font beforehand, but unless you plan to have every contributor to the flowchart write a training letter, this is not an option. It seems there is some industry demand for this kind of flowchart digitization. I suggest extracting the image of the box label from the scan, and carrying this through for display purposes so the underlying data structure can have abstract box labels.