# Block scheme detection in text document

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

I have image of text document. It includes text and block-schemes. The main problem is to detect block-schemes. I think there are two approaches to solve this task: 1) detect geometric primitive that make up the scheme; 2) detect the whole scheme.

How can I solve this task, please, give me some aproaches.

***UPDATE 1***
I try to detect where in document block-scheme is placed. Example is shown on the picture below. I didn't try to detect text in block-scheme.

***UPDATE 2*** The main problem is that i should find block-schemes in different varieties. Even part of the block-scheme.

[image: Example image]

Comment: Do you want to extract where the text is located ? Like text line segmentation. Can you elaborate your question a bit more, posting an example would be more helpful.

Comment: I tryed to explain.

Comment: Is your algorithm fails on this [image](https://yadi.sk/i/kh8_58WzZ0aY7w) due to ratio value?

Comment: Also I find some decision here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947587/analyzing-a-hand-drawn-flowchart-diagram

Comment: and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636996/opencv-extracting-arrows-from-chart

Comment: and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25691358/recognizing-visio-shapes-in-an-image

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer if there were more examples for the types of diagram you are searching for, but based on the example you have given, here is my attempt of solving it naively.

1) Resize image to a manageable size to improve speed and reduce operations.

2) Use morphological open to cluster all the dark objects together.

3) Binarize the dark objects.

4) Label the objects using openCV connected components. This will give us the bounding box of each region.

5) Cluster overlapping bounding box together.

6) Analyze each bounding box to find the one with diagram. Here you can apply a more sophisticated algorithm like box detection or even arrow detection but in your example, i think a simple box ratio is sufficient.

[image]

Here is the code for the implementation

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


# Function to fill all the bounding box
def fill_rects(image, stats):

    for i,stat in enumerate(stats):
        if i > 0:
            p1 = (stat[0],stat[1])
            p2 = (stat[0] + stat[2],stat[1] + stat[3])
            cv2.rectangle(image,p1,p2,255,-1)


# image name 
img_name = 'test_image.png'
# Load image file
diagram = cv2.imread(img_name,0)
diagram = cv2.blur(diagram,(5,5))

fScale = 0.25
# Make it smaller to speed up everything and easier to cluster
small_img = cv2.resize(diagram,(0,0),fx = fScale, fy = fScale)


img_h, img_w = np.shape(small_img)

# Morphological close process to cluster nearby objects
fat_img = cv2.morphologyEx(small_img,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,None,iterations = 1)

# Threshold strong signals
_, bin_img = cv2.threshold(fat_img,210,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Analyse connected components
num_labels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(bin_img)

# Cluster all the intersected bounding box together
rsmall, csmall = np.shape(small_img)
new_img1 = np.zeros((rsmall, csmall), dtype=np.uint8)

fill_rects(new_img1,stats)


# Analyse New connected components to get filled regions
num_labels_new, labels_new, stats_new, centroids_new = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(new_img1)


# Check for regions that satifies conditions coresponds to diagram

min_dia_width = img_w * 0.1

dia_regions = []
for i ,stat in enumerate(stats):

    if i > 0:
        # get basic dimensions
        x,y,w,h = stat[0:4]

        # calculate ratio
        ratio = w / float(h)

        # if condition met, save in list
        if ratio < 1 and w > min_dia_width:
            dia_regions.append((x/fScale,y/fScale,w/fScale,h/fScale))


# For display purpose
diagram_disp = cv2.imread(img_name)
for region in dia_regions:
    x,y,w,h = region
    x = int(x)
    y = int(y)
    w = int(w)
    h = int(h)
    cv2.rectangle(diagram_disp,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)

labels_disp = np.uint8(200*labels/np.max(labels)) + 50
labels_disp2 = np.uint8(200*labels_new/np.max(labels_new)) + 50




cv2.imshow('small_img',small_img)
cv2.imshow('fat_img',fat_img)
cv2.imshow('bin_img',bin_img)
cv2.imshow("labels",labels_disp)
cv2.imshow("labels_disp2",labels_disp2)
cv2.imshow("diagram_disp",diagram_disp)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Here is the result for another type of input.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Can you test this algorithm using such image [link to image](https://yadi.sk/i/8aorzBnj8Efg_Q)?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I did some parameter tuning and the code is now applicable to both of the images

Comment: Thank you!  What can you propose to realise box or line detection?

Comment: Is your algorithm fails on this [image](https://yadi.sk/i/kh8_58WzZ0aY7w) due to ratio value?

Comment: yes. i believe so. Which is why it would be helpful if you share all types of diagram you wish to detect. Why is the last image you share contain cropped diagram? Is it suppose to be cropped? A line detection of box detection can be realize by using template matching. Find regions that contains arrows or square boxes to obtain diagram region

Comment: The main problem is that i should find block-schemes in different varieties. Even part of the block-scheme.

Comment: i see, i think you need to update your question to express your needs properly.

Answer (score 3):

You can either do 1) Object Detection 2) Semantic Segmentation. I would suggest segmentation because boundary extraction is crucial for your application.

I'm assuming you have the pages of the documents as images.

The following are the steps involved in projects involving segmentation.

#### Dataset

1. Collect the images of the pages required to solve you problem and do
   preprocessing steps such as image resizing to bring all images in
   your dataset to a common shape and to reduce the number of computations performed. Be sure to maintain variability in your samples.
2. Now you have to annotate the regions of the images that you are interested and mark them with a name. Here assigning a class (like classification) to certain regions of the image. You can use the following tools for this.

[Labelme](https://github.com/wkentaro/labelme) -- (my recommendation)

[Vgg Annotation tool](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/software/via/) -- (highly portable tool written in html but has less features than labelme)

#### Model

You can use U-Net Model for your task. [Unet Paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.04597.pdf). It is very easy to implement but performs very robustly on most real-world tasks such as yours.

We have done something similar at work. This is the [blog post](https://labs.imaginea.com/post/measuring-feet-using-deep-learning/.). We have explained in detail the steps involved in the pipe line from the data collection stage to the results.

#### Literature on Document Layout Analysis.

1. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.10371.pdf -- They have used U-Net with ResNet-50 as encoder. They have achieved very good results compared to previous approaches
2. https://github.com/leonlulu/DeepLayout--  This is a Python implementation of page layout analysis tool using a Deep Lab v2 model which does semantic segmentation.

#### Conclusion

The approach presented here might seem tedious and time consuming but it is robust to variability in the documents when you are testing. Comment below if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I like DNN, but may be you can propose more simple realisation of block-scheme detection, because DNN is very computational cost expensive? Or may be you can get me link to article?

Comment: thank you for your very helpful answer, could you please help understand why you recommend using Labelme, for your work you have used VGG annotator.

Comment: Labelme is my personal choice because of the features it offers and the ease of use. VGG annotator was my team's choice (I lost the vote :( ).